# PHP sort array elements by key with mixed letters and numbers

Tags: php, sorting

I have a PHP array that has keys like

```
[p1]
[p2]
[...]
[p10]
[p11]
[p12]
[...]
[p20]
[p21]
...
```

I tried to use ksort, but the result looks like

```
[p1]
[p10]
[p11]
[p2]
[p21]
[...]
```

My questions is that, is it possible to somehow use a native php function to sort by both string AND numeric values altogether.

My backup plan is to just explode or substr the key, then sort, but either way they might be slower.

Any idea or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Use the `SORT_NATURAL` flag

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, really appreciate it. I got it working. Somehow I missed that flag.